# C# - Office Interop Word Formatting indents of TableOfContent entries

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I'm creating [TableOfContents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.tableofcontents?view=word-pia) (TOC) in the Microsoft Word Document using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word with entries in the TOC from custom heading styles. My code:

```
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;  
Word.Range rangeForTOC = document.Range(0, 0);
Word.TableOfContents toc = document.TablesOfContents.Add(Range: rangeForTOC, UseHeadingStyles: false);  
toc.HeadingStyles.Add("CustomHeading1", 1);  
toc.HeadingStyles.Add("CustomHeading2", 2);
toc.Update();
```

The question is - how can i apply any style formatting (like left indents and similar stuff that can be easily applied to [Paragraph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.paragraph?view=word-pia) objects) to the TOC entries of selected level of the heading?

I know, that i can apply some formatting to the whole TOC by selecting the [Range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.range?view=word-pia) of the table:

```
Word.Range rngTOC = toc.Range;
rngTOC.Font.Size = 14;
rngTOC.Font.Name = "Times New Roman";
```

But still can't find the way to select only specific entries of the created TOC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each of the possible nine TOC levels there's a corresponding TOC style (TOC 1, TOC 2, etc.) That's where you change how the TOC looks.

These are built-in styles so you should be able to access them using the Word.WdBuiltinStyle enumeration.

Note that if the code is using a template or "default document" as the starting point that it would be more efficient to make these adjustments their than applying them in your code.